# Chrome is not communicating changes in my browser to my local files

Tags: css, google-chrome, webpack, sass, google-chrome-devtools

**The Issue:**

I'm trying to use chrome workspaces / source maps to update my sass partials as I edit CSS in chrome dev tools. Chrome is detecting my sass partials from source maps I setup in webpack, but giving me the error "Changes to this file were not saved to the file system." when I try to save the changes from the sources tab in chrome dev tools.

Moreover, in the styles tab of chrome dev tools, despite chrome knowing which properties are connected to which sass partials, changing the styles there doesn't update the partial files in the sources tab.

Chrome is not communicating changes in my browser to my local files, despite the sass partials showing up as source mapped in the chrome dev tools, and despite me setting up a workstation.

**So far:**

- I set up a workspace in chrome and added the folder for the project
- Disabled all my chrome extensions
- Made sure 'enable css source maps' was true in chrome settings

I believe the problem might be my webpack config, since this is the first time I've made a custom webpack config, and I basically fiddled around with it until it worked. It could (probably not) be a problem with with a dependency, so I'll also add my package.json file.

**Sass partial detected in chrome inspector**

[image]

**Sass partials showing up in sources tab:**

[image]

**Error Message**

[image]

**Webpack config file:**

```
const path = require('path')
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin")
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
    entry: ['@babel/polyfill', './src/index.js'],
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/'
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: 'dist',
        historyApiFallback: true
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: 'index.html',
            template: './src/public/index.html'
        }),

        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: "[name].css",
            chunkFilename: "[id].css"
        })
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.sass$/,
                use: [
                    "style-loader",
                    { loader: 'css-loader', options: { sourceMap: true} },
                    { loader: 'sass-loader', options: { sourceMap: true } }
                ],
            },

            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    "style-loader",
                    "css-loader"
                ]
            },

            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    "babel-loader"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**Package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "css",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack --mode development",
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.6.4",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.6.3",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.6.3",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "css-loader": "^3.2.0",
    "eslint": "^6.5.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.16.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.8.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "webpack": "^4.41.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.9",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.8.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.6.0",
    "react": "^16.10.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.10.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "eslint:recommended",
      "plugin:react/recommended"
    ],
    "env": {
      "browser": true,
      "node": true
    }
  },
  "eslintIgnore": [
    "webpack.config.js"
  ]
}
```

Comment: these screenshots illustrate Devtools interface, nothing to do with the code on them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is no longer supported in Chrome :( Relevant issue is marked as "won't fix".

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=996226

Comment: That's too bad. For anyone that reads this, you can still get the same functionality using a chrome extensioned called LiveStyle, which is what I ended up using. Has to be SCSS though, and not SASS.

Comment: yeah, it's a real bummer! 
thanks for mentioning an alternative, will have a check it out